# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

We have a Javascript conflict and in we see the message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel'

The error is in the file custom.js at line 9.

This is for the staging site: http://vitamine-b12.org/testshop/index.php/nl/

By this issue our slider is not working anymore. The script in custom.js is:

[image]

Line 9 is: jQuery('#featured').jcarousel();

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're correctly loading the jcarousel plugin? This is needed to use this method.

Take a look here:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Moreover you have other errors on the page:

1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hosting24.skyberate.net/~wearelab/skin/frontend/default/labels/css/brands.css

2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'observe' of null cartview.js:1

Plus the one you mentioned:

3) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel'

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not really known with javascript. The thirst one we can fix. After installing our newest module (exploded menu) the issues started. I did not see the cartview.js, but that one is also important because it makes a dropdown form the "winkelwagen" cart. So a ajax cart view. Do you know how to fix the two?

Comment: For the 2nd you must be sure you have in the page an object called 'cartview', as this is returning null: $('cartview')

Comment: Dear Andrea, Thanks for your reply. We have fixed the issue. The Jquery was loaded double, so we disabled it in one of the modules. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to hear it, Coen. Feel free to upvote and accept my answer if you think it helped you to solve the issue.